# how to disable Bootstrap links hover background color?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, background-color

I integrated Bootstrap menu in my web site that I am developing now. In fact, I would like to know how can I disable Bootstrap links hover background color ?. The explanation is as below:

This is the menu that I integrated:

[image]

When I put the mouse cursor over an item of the menu, its background color changes to blue:

[image]

What I want is that when I put the mouse cursor over any item nothing happens, it means that its background color doesn't change at all.

This is the part of css code I am using:

```
.notif_link:hover{
            background-color: inherit !important;
        }
```

And this is the code line belonged to an item of the menu I am using:

```
<li class="notif"><a class="notif_link" href="#"><span class="notif_content">hello</span></a></li>
```

So, my question is what is the error here?..And how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either find the :hover pseudo selector in the Bootstrap css itself and change the value or overwrite it with the same selector (that you can find in dev tools/inspector) using your desired color.

Comment: Ah, also remove the !important declaration. It is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<a class="notif_link" href="#"><li class="notif"><span class="notif_content">hello</span></li></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a[href]:after { display:none;} (or)<a class="disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">LINK</a>
```